# Knockout data table appending values (not reloading)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, datatables

I am issues having refeshing my knockout.js DataTabls. So I have  a data table that loads correctly on page load (ie attached:function method) , I have multiple buttons that (Display All, Allowed, Not Allowed) that displays the table based on the conditions. Now, when I click on the these buttons the table gets reloaded once again, ie if I have 5 records existing I will see 10 (5+5) after I click on the button. This only happens once (ie it stays at 10 and does not reach 15,20...)

Here is my view model 
Original method :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/listusers/GetContractorList",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    headers: appsecurity.getSecurityHeaders(),

    success: function (result) {
        if (result != null) {
            var mappedContractorList = $.map(result, function (item) {
                return new GKContractorObj(item);
            });

            viewmodel.ContractorList(mappedContractorList);

            tableObj= $('#tblContractorsList').DataTable()

        }
    },
    failure: function (error) {
        logger.logError('Failed to contractor list', 'Error', null, true);
    }
});
```

Ajax call when DisplayAll button is clicked

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/listusers/GetContractorList",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    headers: appsecurity.getSecurityHeaders(),

    success: function (result) {
        if (result != null) {
            var mappedContractorList = $.map(result, function (item) {
                return new GKContractorObj(item);
            });

            viewmodel.ContractorList(mappedContractorList);

            tableObj = $('#tblContractorsList').DataTable();


        }
    },
    failure: function (error) {
        logger.logError('Failed to contractor list', 'Error', null, true);
    }
});
```

The view :

```
<div class="divListGKContractor">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="listContractor">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">
          <table id="tblContractorsList" class="display table table-condensed table-bordered table-responsive" cellspacing="0">
            <thead><tr><td>Contractor Details</td><td>Details</td></tr></thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: ContractorList">
              <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Contractor_Name"></td>
                <td>               
                   <a title="List_Contractor" class="btn-borderless widget-button" data-bind="click: $root.listContractorDetails">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit text-success"></i></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I dont think there is any issue with the controller call. Its just that i'm not sure how to refresh / reload the table.

Any help/ suggestions ?

Comment: What is tableObj = $('#tblContractorsList').DataTable(); doing?

Comment: Can you also verify in the browser debugging tools that only 5 records are returned from the server when clicking DisplayAll?

Comment: And can you please include the all the code in your viewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code clears the table on load and solved the issue.

```
//Clear table on load 
viewmodel.ContractorList([]);
tableObj.destroy();
$('#tblContractorsList tbody tr').remove();
```